# component structure in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

First: I'm using Vue since last night, so the answer is probably obvious.

I find components with that layout:

```
<template>
  <Slider v-model="value"/>
</template>

<script>
import Slider from '@vueform/slider'

export default {
  components: { Slider },
}
</script>

<style src="@vueform/slider/themes/default.css" />
```

but at the same time, I also find components that are structured like a JS object:

```
app.component('button-counter', {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: `
    <button @click="count++">
      You clicked me {{ count }} times.
    </button>`
})
```

Is there a practical difference? is one preferred? is one more Vue2 vs. Vue3?

Comment: Hi, The main difference is that the first one helps you to properly organize your components in more understandable manner. It is also helpful when you are dealing with a number of different components.

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax called `SFC` [single file component](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html) :

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
...
</script>

<style src="@vueform/slider/themes/default.css" />
```

which requires a bundler like webpack or vue cli to be transpiled, the second syntax (your example is based on vue 3) is used to define global component which could work if you're using Vue via CDN,

the first syntax is preferred when you setup a medium/large projects.